# Crear un pdf a partir de un html pero con enlaces

Tags: javascript, php, html5, pdf

creo que esta es una pregunta de nivel inicial prácticamente, resulta que quiero generar en PDF documentación de APIS, y documentación en general, algo así como JSDOC pero con formato pdf, ya que en muchas empresas piden entregables en dicho formato.

Ya hice la tarea de buscar en publicaciones, librerías, leí documentaciones de JSPDF y de DOMPDF pero aun así no entiendo como lograr que lea cuando trasforma a PDF mi etiqueta de enlace o hipervínculo.

Comment: ¿Lo has probado?  Quizas ya lo hagan automaticamente reconociendo los enlaces ¿Que has probado? ¿Y que error te han dado? ¿Que ha sucedido?

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta: ¿como lograr que lea cuando transforma en PDF mi etiqueta de enlace o hipervínculo? Por lo general, se requiere generar un documento en pdf a partir de datos que guarda el sistema en base de datos, para lo cual vas a necesitar PHP (veo que lo mencionas en la etiqueta) y trabajar con librerías, por ejemplo: html2pdf, que básicamente tienes que diseñar el documento como una tabla HTML con los datos a introducir, luego capturas el buffer, se lo pasas a la librería y te genera el PDF y lo guarda en un directorio que le digas, luego puedes descargarlo con enlace

Comment: Hola, gracias por sus respuestas, cada cosa que encontré la probé antes de publicar este hilo, en realidad cuando genero un PDF con la librería, no me lee las etiquetas <a href="#page2">Capitulo 2</a>, me genera un PDF con el texto de la etiqueta a pero en texto plano